# RegEx: number range excluding specific number

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

- Using PHP

I am struggling to find an answer on how to use regex to match on a range of numbers, but excluding one number

ie:  I am looking for ANY match of - AM19/0601  - AM19/0805  (but NOT AM19/0803)

I am using this for seeing if I have any match on:

AM19/6XX AM19/7XX AM19/8XX

```
/AM19\/0[678]
```

As in:

```
if (preg_match('/AM19\/0[678]/', $perm) === 0) {
    //do whatever
}
```

But how to I 'exclude' the AM19/803 option as to NOT return/or be included in the match/search?

Comment: I was at RegEx101..  but I wasnt sure HOW to implement the negative lookahead...

I was doing it like so, which obviously was incorrect syntax:

    "AM19\/0[678](?!^AM19\/803$)"

Comment: @anubhava
Thank you for the reply... when I tested that in RegEx101.. It only seemed to return 1 match:

    AM19/0(?!803)[678]

Example String:
    AM19/0601,AM19/0602,AM19/0803

Shouldnt it match on 2?  (I dont need a count to be clear.. just curious)

Comment: @whispers: Check my answer and demo link below. It returns all other matches fine. You kay also see: https://regex101.com/r/X0Un7G/2

Comment: That is different that what you posted above... why?  What are the differences? And why use one over another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a negative lookahead assertion in your regex:

```
~\bAM19/0(?!803)[678]\d{2}\b~
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/X0Un7G/1)

Here we have a negative lookahead `(?!803)` after matching `19/0` which will fail the match if `803` appears right after `19/0` in input.

Also note that by using an alternate regex delimiter `~` you can avoid escaping `/` in your regex.

Comment: What has changed form your original answer?  What differs?  And why?
*** ~AM19/0(?!803)[678]~ ***  vs. ***   ~\bAM19/0(?!803)[678]\d{2}\b~  ***

Comment: Even if you use regex in my comment i.e. `~AM19/0(?!803)[678]` it will still find same number of matches

Comment: you are correct..I did NOT have the flags set..  How do I set them in my PHP preg_match pattern now?  (instead of at RegEx101?)

Comment: No flags needed, just use `~\bAM19/0(?!803)[678]\d{2}\b~` in a `preg_match_all` function instead of `preg_match`

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
\bAM19/(?!0803)\d+
```

Or even

```
(?:AM19/0803)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|AM19/\d+
```

The latter might be a bit over the top, see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/enlQ7g/1/).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a negative lookahead or anything like that. Square brackets can accept multiple ranges (as in `[a-zA-Z]`, for example). You could just ignore the unwanted number using multiple digit ranges.

**Solution:** `AM19\/0[6-8][0-9][0-24-9]`

**Regex101:** https://regex101.com/r/6Zc6br/3